# Visual Studio Time Tracking Plugin

Tags: visual-studio, time-tracking

Is there a plug-in for Visual Studio that will track time spent on a project as well as the files being worked on?

It would be really useful to be able to generate a report each day with the projects worked on the files that were being worked would be used to match up a task to the time.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843328/an-add-on-to-keep-track-of-total-hours-worked-on-a-project-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [TargetProcess](http://www.targetprocess.com/)

However, it does way more than tracking time, so it might not be appropriate to what you want to have.

Comment: This solution is good, but doesn't "track ... the files being worked on" as requested in the OP, does it?

Answer (score 12):

Check out [WakaTime](https://wakatime.com/visual-studio), open-source on GitHub:

https://github.com/wakatime/visualstudio-wakatime

It gives you a dashboard of your logged time:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can try my recently released [Visual Time Spent](http://www.svprogramming.net/visual-time-spent/index.html) add-in. It integrates with Visual Studio and tracks time spent on solutions, projects and files.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using TFS you can track time allocated to Work Items in your team project using [TFS Working On](http://www.codeplex.com/TFSWorkingOn)

Seems pretty straight forward to setup and use... although I do not have experience using it for any length of time.

Comment: I'm not using TFS so I'm not sure how much it will help

Answer (score 0):

[time cockpit](http://www.timecockpit.com) has a feature called "signal trackers". Those track what you are doing, encrypt the data, synchronize it between your devices and presents it in a Calendar style application. You can therefore easily derive what you have been doing when and reconstruct your day.

In your situation, it would track the active window title (showing the solution file) as well as the file writes you had (tells you the files you changed). So you would probably get decent hints on what you have been working at.

I can't be objective here, as I am one of the devs, but it works quite well for our customers as well as us internally.