# An add-on to keep track of total hours worked on a project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, time, tracking

Is there an extension to VS2010 that will keep track of total hours spent on a project? So a developer can see how much time he has contributed into a development of a particular solution.

Comment: Define contribution. (Insert big cheesy grin here)

Comment: A developer would think this through. But my guess - time of opened Visual Studio (and also app being debugged from within it) instance, with the target project loaded. When the VS main windows is minimized, or goes into background, a count-up pauses. This would ofcause exclude the time of research, but nevertheless.

Comment: You could get some numbers no doubt, How they'd relate to contribution is a dubious proposition at best. Aside from detecting 'something' is happening, whether that's the right something is another ball game. Entire proposition is flawed as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion, Tony. Just not I've been reading a post on developer interviews, where a simple tasks of writing a solution fast were discussed. I decided to try myself. Well, the solution was there, but again, if I had a counter built into the VS, as I described, I would know exactly, how long did it take me to solve the task.

Comment: Oh one of those. I'ma tortoise type myself...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20872822/736079